# How to calculate Decimal number of one's compliment in swift?

Tags: swift, binary, hex, decimal

I have a decimal number and I want to convert first 8 bits of that number into one's compliment(Even If it's more than 8 bits number) ..

For Example I have number 633 while I convert this to binary form it will be  0010 0111 1001

When I do one's compliment of first 8 bits it's become 1000 0110 and the decimal number of this binary is 134 ..

I am trying to achieve this by programmatically please help ..thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without even converting to binary:

```
let n = 633
let result = 255 - n % 256
print(result) // 134
```

Modding the number with `256` yields the lower order 8 bits and subtracting that from `255` performs the 1's complement.

You can get the same result by using `& 255` or `& 0xff` to get the low order 8 bits:

```
let result = 255 - n & 255
```

You can also perform the 1's complement by XOR-ing with `255` using the `^` operator:

```
let result = (n & 255) ^ 255
```

---

If you insist on converting to binary and doing the complement, then you could do it like this:

```
let n = 633
let binary = String(n, radix: 2)
let lowbits = ("0000000" + binary).suffix(8)
let complement = String(lowbits.map { $0 == "0" ? "1" : "0" })
let result = Int(complement, radix: 2)!

print(result) // 134
```

Comment: thanks for the help ..   one more help after i dii this i am trying to convert that into hex value and after that trying to add it to data object ..                                                     
   let n = 585
   let result = 255 - n % 256
   let hexValue = String(result, radix: 16)
   var returnMsg = "[1,1,1, ,#77888990".data(using: .utf8) as! Data
   returnMsg.append(UInt8(hexValue)!) // here it's crashing bcz hex value b6 any help? thanks in advance

Comment: That's another question for Stack Overflow.  Post it along with what you tried and the result you expect.